# Workaround for VB.NET partial method using CodeDom?

Tags: vb.net, codedom, partial-methods

I know CodeDom doesn't support partial methods, but is there a workaround? I found a [workaround for C#](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/786d890d-dcbb-4897-9011-240186e177a8), but I need one for VB.NET. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up detecting the language and using CodeSnippetTypeMember()

```
Dim onDeleting = "Partial Private Sub OnDeleting()" & Environment.NewLine & "End Sub"
type.Members.Add(New CodeSnippetTypeMember(onDeleting))
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a horrible hack, as wicked as the C# one, but it does work:

```
Imports System.CodeDom
Imports System.CodeDom.Compiler
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim unit As New CodeCompileUnit
        Dim nspace As New CodeNamespace("SomeNamespace")
        Dim vbclass As New CodeTypeDeclaration("SomeClass")
        vbclass.IsClass = True
        Dim snippet As New CodeSnippetTypeMember("Partial _")
        vbclass.Members.Add(snippet)
        Dim method As New CodeMemberMethod()
        method.Name = "SomeMethod"
        method.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Private
        vbclass.Members.Add(method)
        nspace.Types.Add(vbclass)
        unit.Namespaces.Add(nspace)

        dim provider As CodeDomProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("VB")
        Dim options As New CodeGeneratorOptions()
        options.BlankLinesBetweenMembers = False
        dim writer As new StringWriter()
        provider.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(unit, writer, options)
        Console.WriteLine(writer.ToString())
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Note that the BlankLinesBetweenMembers option is crucial to make the hack work.  Output:

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On

Namespace SomeNamespace
    Public Class SomeClass
Partial _
        Private Sub SomeMethod()
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'd rather not affect all my generated code by changing the BlankLinesBetweenMembers option for this one little hack.